# MySQL PHP Column Update Query

Tags: php, mysql

i would really appreciate if anyone can help me out with this mysql php problem of which i have no idea how to do it.

I Have a column named = 'x'

The text of that column 'x' is = "yz,zz,zy"

I want to edit the value of the column 'x' to = "yz,zyz,zy".

Now how do i add that 'y' in the middle term between yz and zy using **CONCAT**.

Regards.

Comment: You are expected to make some attempt to solve your problem before you post a question. If you have already done so, please include the code that you tried, describe the result, and explain what debugging you have already done.  If you have not even tried yet, please do so now.

Comment: You need an UPDATE query: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Comment: This kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor design. I would encourage you to read up on normalisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided any code or an attempt for us to go off of something so I'll give you a brief way of doing it. Look up PDO [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) This is a really easy to follow and secure way to manipulate data in your database using php. Again as you haven't given me much to go off i'm unsure if you want to just set something at specific count of characters along OR if you want to just update the entire thing, SO i'll help you with the latter as it will help give you some base understanding.

Please read into **PDO** further as this is just an example further down the line and will not run if you just blindly copy and paste it in.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "test";

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


$sql = "UPDATE table SET x='yz,zyz,zy' WHERE id= 1"; // No clue if you've even given anything IDs

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();

echo $stmt->rowCount() . " records UPDATED";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
?>
```

As you haven't really provided any Schema of the table you are updating this is the best I could provide based off of what you have given me.. try to include as much information as possible as I'm unsure if this is what you even want

Comment: It's okay, everything is a learning curve, however everyone's issues are different, so as much detail as possible helps provide accurate responses and keep everyone happy!. Is this what you actually needed?

Comment: Thank you for the help and i am sorry i did'nt share as much information , my bad. i want to use CONCAT to update the column value for example , "UPDATE tablename SET x=CONCAT('zz', 'y') " this statement would append the y but i want to add the y between 'zz', and again the whole value of the column is "yz,zz,zy" using CONCAT how can i change it to "yz,zyz,zy".

Comment: Concatenation just appends two strings together, why would you not just update it instead of inserting a singular letter at one point?  Seems a very bizarre way to go about it in my opinion

Comment: Again though, we're not here to write code for you, if you made some form of effort we can guide you, but for the time being i'd suggest reading through this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: Let me explain in-depth, the table value is = filename,filepath,filesize. the user can change the filepath anytime if they want. now i need a statement which can replace the filepath with the new one which was added by the user. you might be thinking why i dont create 3 different columns for filename , filepath and filesize respectively, well because the table has 1 column for each folder and in that column it contains about 5-10 different files details. total number of folders is about 30 to 35 depending on some circumstances.i do not know if i am able to explain it correctly.

Comment: @AmirQureshi "the table has 1 column for each folder and in that column it contains about 5-10 different files details"  Redesign your database ASAP.  You'll thank yourself later.

Comment: Alright , thanks for the replies everyone i really appreciate them. @PatrickQ